# How to setup Amazon SNS through CloudFormation for push notification? Is this possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to setup Amazon SNS for sending push notification through CloudFormation (including uploading certificate/API key) so that my application can access PlatformApplication ARN through environment variables.

I know how to do it via the AWS console but I am more interested doing it through CloudFormation. I read the Amazon SNS CloudFormation documentation but couldn't find any help from there.

So my question is:

Is this possible to setup / configure Amazon SNS for mobile push using CloudFormation (including uploading certificate/API key) and how?

A sample CloudFormation snippet would be much appreciated.

Comment: Side-note: You might receive more responses if you show us what you have tried and highlight what specific problem you are experiencing, rather than asking for for a total solution. Also, can you provide a link to the documentation for what you mean by "uploading certificate/API Key"? I'm not familiar with doing that for SNS.

Answer (score 3):

[Amazon CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SNS.html) currently supports the following SNS resources types :

- ***AWS::SNS::Subscription***
- ***AWS::SNS::Topic***
- ***AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy***

This means that, currently it is not possible to create SNS platform application and upload API keys/tokens or certificate using CloudFormation in AWS.

You will need to use the currently supported platform e.g SNS ***REST API*** [CreatePlatformApplication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformApplication.html), ***SDK*** or ***CLI*** [create-platform-application.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/create-platform-application.html)

Comment: how to add create platform application code in lambda and create it only once because  it creates multiple times if that lambdas are triggered multiple times